# How to keep formats when I copy a range from Excel to outlook

Tags: excel, vba, format

Hello i have an Excel table with some formats **10(Red)** -> **15(Green)**, but at the end I loose all the formats i have in my excel. I use the next code to send and email from a range to outlook

```
Sub email()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim hoja As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim celdas As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set rng = Range("C3:Q22")
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

        .To = "juan"
        .CC = "Maria"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "XXXX"
        .HTMLBody = "Hey" & RangetoHTML(rng)

        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Kill Fname
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

and the next function, I copied from the next link [How to send mails from excel](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail4.htm)

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found how to made it, in rangetoHtml(), when is pasting the values I changed the code for:

```
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Becase If I made just a copy and paste I dont lost any format.

Answer (score 3):

While OP's accepted answer may have worked for him, I don't believe it's the right answer.

If you want to keep the formatting from your source you need to use **[xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/range/m/pastespecial/)**

**Code:**

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
End With
```