# Keeping conditional formatting when cell copied into Outlook Email

Tags: excel, vba

I used the codes from [ron de bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

It works except the conditional formatted cells with color is not the color it is supposed to be in email body.

In the net the closest problem was fixed when changed to this:

```
'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    '.Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

I tried all the methods in the link [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201709/how-to-keep-formats-when-i-copy-a-range-from-excel-to-outlook)

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: It's version 1808

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work on Outlook 2007 and up.

```
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document

Sheet1.Range("B2:B4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'/* use CreateObject if Outlook is not running */
Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With olEmail
  '/* below is the shortcut version */
  '.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.PasteAndFormat 13
  Set olInsp = .GetInspector
  If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
    Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
    'wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 13 'wdChartPicture /* paste as picture */
    wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 16 'wdFormatOriginalFormatting
  End If
  .Display
End With
```

I used late-bind so no need to set reference to outlook or word.
Commented the type of objects declared so you can check it out in MSDN.
This works on all type of formatting, hidden cells etc. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HTML object.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm