# How do I incorporate a changing variable and add conditionally formatted cell rows to an Outlook email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, conditional-formatting

The overall goal is to go through the entire Excel worksheet (~4000 rows), check column F for a value, if that value is met then check column N for another value (a person's name), if that's met then check the entire row for cells that have been conditionally formatted to be red. If any are found, create an Outlook email that copies over any row with conditional formatting that was found and send to the recipient once. Repeat but change the column N value to the next person and the email address to match.

I am trying to figure out how to loop through my code without having to stack the code 12 more times and manually changing the variables to check as this could inflate to 100 people in the future.
I'd also like to copy rows that contain conditionally formatted cells to the automated email so the user doesn't need to open the SharePoint to check their information.

I tried following [Keeping conditional formatting when cell copied into Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597837/keeping-conditional-formatting-when-cell-copied-into-outlook-email) but the original code from Ron de Bruin is gone.

This code works for an individual user but I haven't been able to figure out how to copy rows over that meet the conditional formatting:

```vb
Sub OutlookEmailAlerts()
Dim outlookApp As Object
Dim outlookMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim emailSent As Boolean
Dim redColorFound As Boolean
Dim singleCell As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A:Z")
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    emailSent = False
    
    For Each cell In rng.Rows
        redColorFound = False
        If cell.Cells(1, 6).Value = "78550" Then
            If cell.Cells(1, 14).Value = "Person 1's name" Then
                For Each singleCell In cell.EntireRow.Cells
                    If singleCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                        redColorFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next singleCell
                If redColorFound And Not emailSent Then
                    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                    With outlookMail
                        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                        .display
                        .To = "Person A's email address" 
                        .Subject = "Alerts"
                        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-size:11pt; font-family: Calibri;'>Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "This is an automated email to alert you that you have items that need to be addressed. Please refer to the Sharepoint file for details.</p>" & .HTMLBody
                        .send
                    End With
                    emailSent = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

How do I loop through the code while changing condition 2 to a different person's name and the recipient email address to correspond with the changed variable? (There will be at least 12 more people I'd have to check).

Also, how do I copy the flagged rows in condition 3 to the email instead of having the user visit SharePoint?