# Range To HTML removing part of the string

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

All,

I have been using the below code to generate an email which compiles a range into an HTML body of an email.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StrBody As String
Set rng = Nothing

Sheets("HTML Loop").Activate 'Change
Set sht = ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = sht.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If sht.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

StrBody = "All," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
          "The Robot has completed its daily check of the FX3 Site and has created " & lastrow & " new folder location(s)." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
          "*Please review the files located here:"

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "Sean.B@xxx.co.uk"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily FX3 Notification Email " & Now()
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Thanks" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Gary"
    .Display
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutA

 End sub

 Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim ts As Object
  Dim TempFile As String
  Dim TempWB As Workbook

 TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

The issue I am having is when the email is generated, the strings within the range is cut at 9 Characters long.

The range consists of file paths like the below:

\csdatg09\financial systems\Automation\Pega Projects\Tax\FIN_TAX_GARY\Bristol\TEST TEST 108 EastCott Hill

\csdatg09\financial systems\Automation\Pega Projects\Tax\FIN_TAX_GARY\Exeter\TEST TEST 108 EastCott Hill

I would like to understand why the output is like the screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, this is a duplicate question the answer I was looking for can be found here:

[How to keep formats when I copy a range from Excel to outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201709/how-to-keep-formats-when-i-copy-a-range-from-excel-to-outlook)

Specific Code:

```
   TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```