# Pasting Cell information to body of e-mail using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

How do I get information from say Range A1-B10 onto the body of the e-mail I'm wanting to send using the following Macro:

Currently, it opens an e-mail window & does everything it is supposed to, including attaching the latest saved copy of the workbook - but I can't figure out how to include & "Range(A1:B10)" & in the .body line.

```
Sub EmailForm()

'Working in Excel 2000-2016


    Dim workbook_Name As Variant
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object


        ThisWorkbook.Save

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "emailaddress@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = " Lot Number " & Range("B37")
        .Body = ""


       .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   ' use .Display or .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe see [this great resource](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm).

Comment: Why not just loop through the range, building a string, then inputting that string? (Also, do you have the formula `TEXTJOIN()`)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549526/3233363 or http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section1.htm

Comment: I see - so no easier way keeping the existing code huh =/

Answer (score 0):

From the link @BigBen pointed out, code by Ron de Bruin

```
Sub EmailForm() 
'Working in Excel 2000-2016


    Dim workbook_Name As Variant
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object


        ThisWorkbook.Save

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "emailaddress@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = " Lot Number " & Range("B37")
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Range("A1:B10"))


       .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   ' use .Display or .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```