# How do I ensure all Conditional Formats are copied when I'm copy and pasting a sheet into a new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, html-email, copy-paste, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to copy a table from a worksheet into an email, using vba and the HTMML function (copy into a new workbook, and then copy into outlook). I have multiple conditional formats on the table, changing the fill of cells, and font colour (white = normal, red = when condition is met). When the table is copied into the new workbook however all the font is becoming red, even when the condition is not met!

I have attempted a variety of different paste specials (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats), as well as trying to make the copied table static in terms of formatting.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
    End If

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim a As Double

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Expected results - table will have fonts in white or red depending on the condition within the cell (as it is on the original sheet)
Actual results - font within the pasted table is all red, despite times when the condition is not met.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create email from Excel-VBA to include Range with Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546903/create-email-from-excel-vba-to-include-range-with-conditional-formatting)

Comment: See the above link...  I had previously asked a similar question for keeping conditional formatting and was answered in that link.  Specifically, see the edit in the accepted answer.

Comment: Hmm i've tried it using xlPasteAll, but it formats all the cells the same way, instead of having the conditional formats

Comment: Charlie, the suggestion would be to abandon that `workbook.add` method and only use `publishobject.add`, which is in the answer from the above linked post.

Comment: Yep thats done it - thank you!