# Run-Time error '438' Object doesn't support this propert or method (Sending Automated Email)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to send a form as a table in Outlook once clicking a button in the sheet. I tried writing a code to take it as a snapshot and it worked but this gave me a hard time while using power query to compile some date from the sent emails .. and I figured out that I have to have the table in the body and not as a snapshot.

I can't seem to figure where is the problem exactly as I am a novel user of VBA.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()



Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FX Request Form")

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)


With newEmail

.to = "belsawy@banquemisr.com"
.CC = ""
.bcc = ""
.Subject = sh.Range("C9").Value
.Body = ""


Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object


Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

sh.Range("B2:C21").Copy

pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

.Send

Set oageEditor = Nothing
Set xInspect = Nothing

End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

MsgBox "Your Request Has Been Sent To The Concerned Departments,Thank You"

End Sub
```

Comment: what line is giving you that error?  have you attempted to compartmentalize your Excel activities to separate them from the Outlook activities (different subroutines)?

Comment: also, see [the edit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549526/3233363) which is a function to capture an excel range into an email

Comment: Now I get Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. The new error appeared when I added .Send This happens when I reach this line "Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)"

Comment: Baelsway, please edit your post to add your new code (`set new email` isn't anywhere in the code you've provided or in the linked answer).  I would think from just reading that you have not set `outlook` to a variable within your module OR you have used `.` (dot) notation without a `with-block` around your use.

Comment: I edit the code to be as what I am using now. Apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: try using `set newemail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)`

Comment: Didn't work … my head is melting.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you.

You have to add ‚.Display’ before ‚Dim xInspect As Object’

Comment: Now I get Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. This happens when I reach this line "Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)"

Comment: Set newemail = oulook (not outlook)

Answer (score 0):

After ensuring that references for outlook are enabled, I think you've got a few general issues.

For your code, you would want to dimension such that:

```
Private newEmail As Outlook.MailItem, outlook As Outlook.Application

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'YOU SPELLED THIS WRONG (forgot the T in outlook)
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

From there, your code seems like it should fit.

What you really need to do is put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, outside of all subroutines, to make sure you can see where "new variables" are being used.