# Why RangetoHTML Type Mismatch Error in Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the rangetohtml function below however when i do rangetohtml("data set") i get a ByRef argument type mismatch - any ideas please?

Its the last error i think i have when i am copiling so any support would be appreciated!

````
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=lHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function```
````

Comment: What line throws the error? Most likely `RangeToHTML` expects a range, not a string.

Comment: Hi Ben - in my sub form i have the below which throws out the error .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(ds) ds being my data from excel

Comment: What's `ds`? Please make your question a [reprex].

Comment: Hi Ben, apologies i am new to all this, please see full code from Sub which reference to the RangetoHTML Function

Comment: ```Set ds = Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
With OutMail
.Display
End With

With OutMail
.Subject = EmailSubject
.To = EmailSendTo
.CC = xCC
'.Body = MailBody
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(ds)
.Display

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
MailBody = ""
End If
With Application
    .EnableEvents = 1
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing: Set OutApp = Nothing

Next


End Sub```

Comment: Do you have `Dim ds As Range`?

Comment: Thank you Ben that has resolved one issue, one left, if you could help that would be great. It copies the data onto the email but doesn't show any value just the headers i think its to do with my filter criteria ```Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Sheets("ContractList").Range("A2").Value
Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*"

    lr = Sheets("SAPExport").Cells(Sheets("SAPExport").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ds = Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Answer (score -1):

Improved function from here:
[Create email from Excel-VBA to include Range with Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546903/create-email-from-excel-vba-to-include-range-with-conditional-formatting)

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Altered from code by Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = rng.Worksheet.Parent

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Publish the sheet range to a htm file
    With wbSrc.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
         Source:=rng.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set wbSrc = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tragamor for some reason i am getting an object or application defined error on this section ```    With wbSrc.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
         Source:=rng.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)

Comment: Without seeing more code or how you are generating the e-mail, it is difficult to help. One point to note is that any range you wish to transform to HTML must be contiguous (i.e. one area, no filtered rows etc.). If you do have a range selected that is non-contiguous then you would need to create what you want to process as one range. (Copying and pasting into a new blank worksheet should work for that)

Comment: A bit more testing and you can use filtered rows to copy the range but the use of .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) throws the error. Try just removing this and use the entire range including hidden rows.

Comment: Thank you all - i have it somewhat working now - i just keep getting office waiting OLE action error :L