# Python: Copy Excel Range and paste with source formatting to outlook email body

Tags: python, outlook

I would like to copy Excel Range and paste with source formatting to outlook email body. However, I do not know how to do that.

My temporary solution exports the excel range to image and paste as **image** onto email. I wonder how can I paste with source formatting onto the outlook email body ?

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("testing.xlsx")
sheet = wb.Sheets['Sheet1']
copyrange = sheet.Range('A1:N9')
copyrange.CopyPicture(Appearance = 1, Format = 2)
ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save('image1.png')
sheet = wb.Sheets['Sheet2']
copyrange2 = sheet.Range('A1:M26')
copyrange2.CopyPicture(Appearance = 1, Format = 2)
ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save('image2.png')
excel.Quit()


# Create outlook email and insert Excel Content
html = """
    <img src={}></img>
    <br><br>
    <img src={}></img>

"""


outlook         = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail            = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject    = 'Testing'
mail.HTMLBody   = html.format("image1.png","image2.png")
mail.Display()
```

Comment: Non-python solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546903/create-email-from-excel-vba-to-include-range-with-conditional-formatting